# PHP: Write to file, and starting where it left off

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm very unfamiliar with PHP...

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("emaillist.txt", "w");
    $newemail = "email1\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $newemail);
    $newemail = "email2\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $newemail);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

The code is to create a database of emails. When going to emaillist.txt, the output is:

```
email1
email2
```

The output will stay like that, even if I run the php file a new line. My desired output is to for example run it twice, and get:

```
email1
email2
email1
email2
```

I'm aware storing emails in .txt files isn't smart, but this isn't for real world use.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `w` mode of [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). To place the file pointer at the **end**, use `a` or `a+`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to do `fopen("emaillist.txt", "a");`instead of `fopen("emaillist.txt", "w");`because a appends to the file, while w just writes to it.